# why does hook_menu produce a menu that belongs to the system module?

Tags: 7, routes, hooks

In my project we implement a little menu that provides information about the module.  This snippet lives in `drutexml.module`.

```
function drutexml_menu() {
  $items['drutexml'] = array(
    'title' => 'LaTeX filter implemented via LaTeXML',
    'page callback' => 'drutexml_information',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

Actually this is a bit silly, and I want to turn it back off inside the installation profile.  But as it turns out...

```
SELECT link_path, module FROM menu_links WHERE link_path = "drutexml";

+-----------+--------+
| link_path | module |
+-----------+--------+
| drutexml  | system |
+-----------+--------+
```

and then in `menu.inc`, where `menu_link_delete` is implemented, we see this  bit of logic on line 2997:

```
if ($item && ($item['module'] != 'system' || $item['updated'] || $force)) { ...
```

In other words, I can only delete non-"system" links.  That's fine with me!  Or it would be, if my link was stored with the name of the module where `hook_menu` is implemented in the first place.

What's going on here?  Why is this said to be a "system" link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to remove a menu item defined from a module in `hook_menu()` is, apart from removing its definition from the module's `hook_menu()`, removing it with [hook_menu_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7).

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  unset($items['drutexml']); 
}
```

Menu items that are part of a menu, including the ones defined with `hook_menu()`, are saved in the menu_links table. Those defined in `hook_menu()` are saved setting the "module" field to "system" to distinguish them from other links directly added from a module.

Comment: What is the alternative to `hook_menu()` for adding links directly from a module?

Comment: You can use `hook_menu()`, but use [MENU_SUGGESTED_ITEM](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/constant/MENU_SUGGESTED_ITEM/7) as type. In that way, the link will appear in a menu if an administrator user enables it.

Comment: Or maybe use [menu_link_save](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_link_save/7)?  Frankly the design decision that says we should "distinguish" `hook_menu` links from other kinds of links seems weird to me.  But any, I think I understand now (sorta).  Thanks!

Comment: You can also use `menu_link_save()`, but the module should also remove the link once it is disabled. I prefer using `MENU_SUGGESTED_ITEM` because the link is automatically removed when the module is disabled; when the module is re-enabled, the link is automatically added where it was before.

Comment: Also, another problem with `menu_link_save()` is that it doesn't straightforwardly allow me to add a `page callback`.  There's considerable discussion about how this will all be rewritten in [D8](http://drupal.org/node/653784) anyway, so I'm not going to worry about it too much...

Comment: Drupal 8 will use Symfony. The routing part is already being rewritten to use it.